# D3 - Update single grid line after data change

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-enter-update-group-children-mt-tbxtau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts

Its a d3 chart in an angular app.

The chart horizinatalk and vertical grid lines.

I would like to style the 100% grid different to the rest

I can do this simply with

```
d3.selectAll('g.tick')
  .filter((d) => d===100)
  .attr('class', 'grid-100')
```

My problem is this doesn't update when the data changes.

How can I style this grid line in the enter and update parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `attr()`, you are replacing the existing class of `tick` (and therefore this particular tick will not be replaced when you call `this.y_axis`).

Use `classed()` instead to add your custom class `.grid-100` while leaving `.tick` in place.

```
  d3.selectAll('g.tick')
      .filter((d) => d===100)
      .classed('grid-100', true)
```

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-enter-update-group-children-mt-abjbdv)